# Android: How do you emulate a keyboard flip?

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation, flip, monkey

While debugging my app using Monkey (which is almost as fun as the real thing), I managed to crash!  Yay, that's what it's for, right?

Looking at the log (and while watching) I noticed that Monkey is occasionally doing:

```
:Sending Flip keyboardOpen=true
```

which seems to be part of my problem.  When this happens, the screen in the emulator rotates 90 degrees, but this is NOT the same as a regular rotation you get by hitting KEYPAD_7.  Here's a picture:

[image: unusual screen orientation]

It looks to me the emulator is emulating a keyboard opening (flip), which is subtly different from a rotation.

So the question is: How do I emulate that myself?  Sure, running Monkey is neat, but waiting for it to randomly choose to send a keyboardOpen message is no way to debug a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the `--pct-majornav` to restrict the monkey to just the 'major' nav events (I'm assuming keyboard changes are 'major', I'm not sure though).

You could also look into writing a specific test based on the different but similar monkeyrunner framework:  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html ... but I don't see any way to inject keyboard flip codes.

I found this relevant SO question:
[Simulating opening/closing the hardware keyboard in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047971/simulating-opening-closing-the-hardware-keyboard-in-emulator) but the "answer" there is confusing and seems insufficient.

Not really your question, but related to your root issue:

Did you forget to include 'keyboardHidden' in the 'android:configChanges' section of the manifest file?  (Or did you include it, but you don't handle the config change callbacks?)

The keyboard hide/reveal will restart your activity.  You can either declare that you handle that restart, or if you don't, the OS will stop and restart the app itself.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

## Update

I believe [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeyFlipEvent.java) is the source for the monkey application's keyboard flip event.  It looks like injecting a keyboard flip event would be relatively straight-forward: Open /dev/input/input0 and write 16 magical bytes into it.

Also, the source seems to have an undocumented --pct-flip option for controlling keyboard flip rates: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/Monkey.java)

Comment: Thanks for the link--I didn't find it during my search. It's sad that it seems there just is NOT a way to emulate purely a keyboard flip/slide (but the Monkey can do it!--sigh). We have to do a rotate AND a flip.  [BTW, my bug WAS related to an odd condition during restarts and EditTexts--fixed it without needing to step through. Thanks!]

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, P.T.!  Unfortunately the links are no longer active, sigh.

This is a real bugger of a situation, but I consider this question answered enough.  If anyone else has more info, please add it to this conversation.

Comment: The source is still available at various other places - try http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-development/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeyFlipEvent.java.htm